# Querying one to many JPA for an entity in a list

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a class called `Customer` and it contains a list of `Account`. I am trying to write a query using JPA to perform a search.

```
@Entity 
class Customer {
private var id: Long = 0 
private var name: String? = null 
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "customer_account",
        joinColumns = [javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "customerId", referencedColumnName = "id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "accountId", referencedColumnName = "id")]
    )
private var account: List<Account>

}

@Entity 
class Account {
private var id: Long =0 
private var amount: Long = 0

}
```

I am trying to run a query that will return a customer object if the account id matches the input.

So in the repository I am trying to:

```
@Query("SELECT c from Customer as c WHERE c.account.id = :id)
fun findCustomerByAccountId(id: Long): Customer
```

However, I am NOT seeing `account.id` I am instead seeing size which tells me that the invocation is on the `Account List` . Is there a way to actually perform this search?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Query("SELECT c from Customer as c WHERE c.account.id = :id)
fun findCustomerByAccountId(id: Long): Customer
```

Your query seems fine but as this result will return a list, you should define it in your method[though I am not familiar with this syntax].
However, I do this like this way:

```
@Query("SELECT c from Customer as c WHERE c.account.id = :id)
List<Customer> findCustomerByAccountId(id: Long): Customer
```